# What's the best approach to keep track of history information in a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I would like to know what are the advantages or disadvantages for these two ways of keeping history information in a table.

I know there are some automatic ways in `SQL Server 2014` like `CDC` or `TDC`, but I want something custom.

Let's say a have an employee table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee
(
    EmployeeId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(50),
    LastName NVARCHAR(50),
    DepartmentId INT,
    StatusId INT,
    CreatedDate datetime,
    ModifiedUserId INT,
    ModifiedDate datetime
)
```

The first way I'm thinking is creating a history table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.EmployeeHistory
(
    EmployeeHistoryId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ActionTypeId INT,   -- INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE
    EmployeeId INT NOT NULL,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(50),
    LastName NVARCHAR(50),
    DepartmentId INT,
    StatusId INT,   
    ModifiedUserId INT,
    ModifiedDate datetime
)
```

For each insert/update/delete, I'll create a new record on this history table keeping all the information.

The second way is to have another history table with a different structure keeping just a record with the specific information that was changed, for example if I'm changing only the `FirstName`, I'll save one record with the old value and the new value and that's it. Here is the structure:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.EmployeeHistory
(
    EmployeeHistoryId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ActionTypeId INT,   -- INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE
    EmployeeId INT NOT NULL,
    FieldName NVARCHAR(50),
    OldValue NVARCHAR(50),
    NewValue NVARCHAR(50),    
    ModifiedUserId INT,
    ModifiedDate datetime
)
```

Comment: This is really an opinion type of question instead of one with an actual right answer. I would stay away from the EAV style of auditing as it makes looking at the entire row at a given point in time incredibly challenging. Also, there is no need to store the new and old values in your audit, the new values will be in the base table.

Comment: @Devart the OP is looking to record the "whodunnit" which CDC doesn't capture.

Comment: Sorry, CDC is Change Data Capture

Comment: According to me second approach is better. My current employer also have same kind of approach and it is really helpful some times.

Comment: thank you for sharing your opinion

Comment: What is "TDC"? Are you talking about the temporal tables that they're implementing in SQL 2016?